# Is a DataFrame with one row much slower to work with than a series?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've run across some legacy code with data stored as a single-row `pd.DataFrame`. 
My intuition would be that working with a `pd.Series` would be faster in this case - I don't know how they do optimization, but I know that they can and do so. 
Is my intuition correct? Or is there no significant difference for most actions? 
(to clarify - obviously the best practice would not be a single row DataFrame, but I'm asking about performance)

Comment: what about the datatypes? are they the same for all items in the row?

Comment: For my purpose, let's say that they are (though I'm also interested in the general case)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes for a large number of columns there will be a noticeable impact on performance.
You should consider that a `DataFrame` is a dict of `Series` so when you perform an operation on the single row, `pandas` has to coalesce all the column values first before performing the operation.

Even for 100 elements you can see there is a hit:

```
s = pd.Series(np.random.randn(100))
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1,100))
%timeit s.sum()
%timeit df.sum(axis=1)


104 µs ± 5.08 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
194 µs ± 2.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

In my opinion there is no reason to have a single row df that couldn't be achieved with a `Series` where the index values are the same as the column names for that `df`

The performance degradation isn't linear as for a 10k array it's not quite 2x worse:

```
s = pd.Series(np.random.randn(10000))
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1,10000))
%timeit s.sum()
%timeit df.sum(axis=1)

149 µs ± 10.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
253 µs ± 36.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: I am saying that one is `10000 ` loops, and ones is `1000` loops.

Comment: @U9-Forward this is to do with `timeit` trying to limit the number of loops if it detects if an operation will take a long time, basically stopping looping 10000 times if something will freeze python

Comment: @EdChum you're right that there is no reason to have a single row df, like I said it's some legacy code that I'm wondering if I should be worried about. Turns out I should!

Comment: @EdChum Also - Thanks for the answer! It helped a lot.